# JavaScript: Checking a list for elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, function

I'm currently learning JavaScript using Marijn Haverbekes excellent book "Eloquent JavaScript". Now there is this exercise where you have to write a recursive function that returns the nth element of a nested list. If there is no such element, the function is supposed to return `undefined`. The solution looks like this:

```
function nth(list, n) {
  if (!list)
    return undefined;
  else if (n == 0)
    return list.value;
  else
    return nth(list.rest, n - 1);
}
```

So far, everything seems pretty clear to me. However, I don't really get what exactly `if (!list) {}` does. How exactly does this condition evaluate? Why is it true, if `list` has an element `n`?

The complete excercise can be found here:
http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#p_7AnSuS26HF

Comment: `if (!list)` checks the empty list

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, the list branch, because it's traversed recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if (!list)
```

Is a shorthand way of saying

```
if (list === false || list === 0 || list === '' || list === null || list === undefined || list !== list /* NaN */) ...
```

---

`!list` will happen in when the list is shorter than `n` elements.

```
// 4 is larger than the list length here, (2)
// !list will happen
nth({value: 'a', rest: {value: 'b', rest: null}}, 4)
//=> undefined

// 1 is not larger than the list length
// !list will not happen
// instead, n === 0 happens after recursing 1 time
nth({value: 'a', rest: {value: 'b', rest: null}}, 1)
//=> 'b'
```

Comment: `list === NaN` always `false`

Comment: @MaxZuber wups. fixed.

Comment: `isNan(list)` casts the `list` to Number type, so it would cause undesired results. Use `list !== list` instead of

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't really get what exactly if (!list) {} does.

It checks if `list` variable still has a value which is other than falsey value such as `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `""` or `''`. If the list has any falsey value, then it returns `undefined`.

> Why is it true, if list has an element n?

As per the link you have shared, value of list is

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

which means either `rest` has child elements or it has `null`.

eventually, it will have `null` which is what this condition will assert and return `undefined`.